# analysing network traffic

Tags: networking, distributed-system, network-traffic

Whats the best way to identify network behavior??
Behavior of the ports/interfaces and routers?
I can get data and analyse the traffic but trying to search for a pattern for a meaningful classification.
Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**WireShark**](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a great tool, too.

Features are similar to other, but one is the exporting to CSV.  You could then import the CSV into Excel and run some analysis there.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick info. My goal here is that i want to categorize the behavior of my interfaces depending on factors like ingress/egress traffic. I have all the data with me. By end of this exercise I want to determine which ports I can get rid of or which is having the least activity.

Comment: I think I need to use some kind of pattern recognition to do this. But unable to get a lead.

Comment: I added another entry for WireShark.  I think with both, specifically WireShark, you can color code endpoints and filter by them.  So, I think you may be able to see where the heavy and light hitters as far as ports go if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I would say **Ethereal** is the best tool out there.

http://www.ethereal.com/

It was some time since I used it, but by what I remember you could choose a number of filters and features like that which made it very clear what was going on.